Using Point Sampling Tool of QGIS
I am trying to sample raster values at locations in a points layer, using the Point Sampling Tool - a process that I have done successfully in the past. The process is failing with a Python error:

ValueError: Null geometry cannot be converted to a point


I have reprojected both the raster and the shape file to make sure that they have the same CRS
I have run the Fix Geometry tool on the shape file
I have run the Check validity tool
I have exported the point layer to a new shape file (the original layer came from a CSV import with geometry in WKT format) and tried with the new layer

...all with no result.
Can you provide any hints?
QGIS 3.30.1
Python 3.9.5
Windows 10

After a comment by @user2856:

You have a null (not invalid) geometry. Don't use the point sampling
tool plugin. Use the core functionality "Sample raster
values"
processing tool which will work and output a result as well as telling
you which feature/s had null geometry.

I eventually found out that the problem was that two points were beyond the extent of the raster, which caused the error.  "Sample raster values" is definitely the better way to go.
